# Json column not updating through Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a weird situation where my json column gets updated using unit test method but not though MVC controller.

Here is Test Method which updates the Phone Number and it's WORKING

```
public void Test_UpdateEmployee()
{
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.Get(emp => emp.Email == "a@b.com").Result.Single();

    employee.UpdatePhones(new List<StringValue> { "888" });
    employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeAsync(employee);
}
```

And here is the Action in controller which does not send update to SQL server for Phone property

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(EditEmployeeViewModel model)
{
    model.Employee.UpdatePhones(new List<StringValue> { "888" });
    await _employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeAsync(model.Employee);

    //All properties get updated, except Phones
    
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Summary:**

I checked through SQL Server Profiler and checked the Update statements,
When using Test Method, `Phone` is included in update command, but saving the entity in controller action, does not included Phone property in update Command.

Note that the Action, updates all other properties like FirstName and LastName, but not updating Phone property which is a json column.

I can't figure out why it's not working in Action while Test Method is working correctly.

I will add more detail for Models and ViewModels if needed.

**Update:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>? orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProp);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task UpdateEmployeeAsync(Employee employee)
{
    dbContext.Employees.Attach(employee);
    var entry = dbContext.Entry<Employee>(employee);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I also noticed if I fetch a new employee object instead of using the `model.Employee`, and assign the properties from `model.Employee` to it, it will work. Looks like something is wrong with the `model.Emoloyee`.

Comment: Can share the implementation of `employeeRepository.Get()` and `employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeAsync()` methods? Suspect that it is due to the entity state for related entities.

Comment: Added the methods. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Can you return a task from the UpdateEmployees Async. The working method is synchronous but the one that fails is not.

Comment: @StuartSmith, I removed async from everywhere and made it synchronous, but the problem persists.

Comment: @StuartSmith, I also returned Task<Employee> from UpdateEmployeeAsync and verified the returned employee has correct Phone. but it is not persisted in database. So looks like dbContext gets updated but not persisted in db.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with dirty solution. I had to save Employee and Phone in different phase.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    // Update Employee from model
    await _employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeAsync(model.Employee);

    // Fetch Employee again from db, update Phones and update entity again.
    var inDb = await _employeeRepository.Get(emp => emp.Id == model.Employee.Id);
    var emp = inDb.Single();
    emp.UpdatePhones(model.Phones);
    _ = await _employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeAsync(emp);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I could not save whole Employee in single save. Seems like a bug in EF Core?